# Trimming dynamic listview Text object

Tags: android, listview, delphi, firemonkey

I have a Dynamic ListView loading some data. One of the items is a string in a TextObject.

I am trying to set the Text Trimming for this text object to `Character`. I have set the properties in the Object Inspector set to `WordWrap: True` and `Trimming: Character`.

On Android, it seems to do nothing, the text continues untrimmed (on Windows, it works fine, and I see the three dots like this: `...`). I thought perhaps I need to do the trimming in code, so I have done this:

```
procedure TfrmJob.lvWorksheetsUpdateObjects(const Sender: TObject;
  const AItem: TListViewItem);
var
  TextObj: TListItemText;
begin
  TextObj := AItem.Objects.FindDrawable('Description') as TListItemText;
  TextObj.Trimming := TTextTrimming.Character;
end;
```

On Android, this code still does not trim the text at all, as before it just keeps going and overflows.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. per the [`TTextTrimming`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Types.TTextTrimming) (and [`TText.Trimming`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TText.Trimming)) documentation:

> Note: For Android and iOS platforms, [Trimming](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TText.Trimming) works only when *[WordWrap](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Objects.TText.WordWrap) = False*.

But, you have `WordWrap` set to `True` instead.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I not sure how I missed that one.